# CMake GUI failed to create directory in /opt/local/

Tags: macos, library

I’m trying to build the [Eigen library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) using the [CMake GUI](http://www.cmake.org/download/). I’ve downloaded the library from the webiste (.tar.bz2), extracted it, and used the extracted path as source location for the CMake GUI, the `CMakeLists.txt` was already provided with it.

I’m able to build the library in other places, but when I set destination path to:

```
/opt/local/DESTINATION_PATH
```

It first asks me if it should create the destination directory as it doesn't exist. When I click yes, it tells me the following and quits:

> FAILED TO CREATE DIRECTORY

I need the library to be built within `/opt/local/`. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say this:

> I’m able to build the library in other places…

But it’s choking here:

> /opt/local/DESTINATION_PATH

While I have not used CMake, in general Unix/Linux context the problem is the `/opt/local/` directory would be owned by root. And if you want to create content in there, you would need to launch CMake via `sudo` so you can gain super user privileges.

According to [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25145785/117259) you can do it like this. First open up the terminal command line and type in this command:

```
sudo /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/MacOS/CMake
```

Next it will ask you for your password. Go ahead and type that in. And when CMake launches it will be via `sudo` so writing to `/opt/local/` should not be an issue.